# How BroadcastReceiver can communicate with Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

How BroadCastReciever can communicate with service without binding?

I thought that it is good idea to use binder in BroadCastReceiver but after reading some info, i understood that it is not a good idea.
I tried to find issue in stackoverflow, but all what i finded is:

Q:"BroadCastReciver + binder"

A:"No, it is bad idea."(without giving examples how to communicate with service without binder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - LocalBroadcastManager.
Thanks to LocalBroadcastManager we can send broadcasts between different part of our app.

**SEND_BROADCAST**

```
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.onezero.EXAMPLE_ACTION");
        localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "=(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, filter);

        Intent sintent = new Intent("com.onezero.EXAMPLE_ACTION");


        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(sintent);
```

**Receive Broadcasts**

```
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.onezero.EXAMPLE_ACTION");
        localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // DO WORK
                setPlayPause(); //PAUSE MEDIAPLAYER IN MY CASE
            }
        }, filter);
```